# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, docker-machine, ibm-blockchain

While setting up a local network via `cmd`, I am currently encountering the following `docker` issue :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 
'/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'.
```

UPDATE

```
C:\Users\user_name>docker run --rm -v "C:\Users\user_name\.fabric-
vscode\environments\1 Org Local Fabric":/network -v 
/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --network host 
ibmblockchain/vscode-prereqs:0.0.16 ansible-playbook /network/playbook.yml
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:
```

and thus look for suggestions to overcome this `setup` issue.

Comment: I think if you use Docker for Windows (with linux containers) this might fix the problem - can you give that a go and report back?

Comment: @Jake: I think that the adequate Docker version (v.19.03.8) has been used, since ```docker run -it bash ubuntu``` does work, downloading the newer image for ubuntu.

Comment: @david_k: Microsoft ```Windows version 1909``` (```OS Build 18363.1198```)  ```Pro```. ```cmd docker version```  leads to  ```Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      true```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your environment ? What version of windows are you using, Are you using Docker for Windows or DockerToolbox (one uses hyper-v while the other uses virtualbox) ? If so which version, for example my version is 2.5.0.1 which was displayed when I installed the docker for windows version. Make sure you aren't using docker toolbox as this won't work.

Comment: @david_k: done (see above), hoping that it helps.

Comment: @dark.vador Unfortunately the output of the cli command doesn't tell me which version of docker you are actually using whether it's docker toolbox or docker desktop and what actual release. I would recommend using WSL2 for your docker environment and a description of how to can be found here https://davidkel.github.io/docs/vscode/windows.html. This will mean installing a set up updates for windows and the edge release of docker desktop (as you aren't at windows feature release 2004 as yet). But WSL2 makes using Docker on windows a much better experience

Comment: You should be able to get the latest edge version here https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows/

Comment: @david_k: Extremely grateful David! Thanks a lot, since your latest feedback did help me in sorting this issue out.